# Explicitly specify packages in each package json

Tags: node.js, package.json, lint, monorepo, yarn-v2

Yarn recently introduced berry along with PnP for dependency management. For a number of reasons, I can't update the policy from node_modules to PnP.

However, I find the mechanism for checking that each package used must be explicitly listed in package.json for all packages in monorepo very useful.

Is there some way to enable it for the node_modules strategy to be one step closer to PnP and avoid sticky situations?

Let's say I have monorepo with `packageA` and `packageB`

```
.
├── node_modules
├── packages/
│   ├── packageA/
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── packageB/
│       ├── node_modules
│       └── package.json
└── package.json
```

If I add the `libA` library as a `packageA` dependency, it ends up in the node_modules folder at the root of the project, since it hasn't been used anywhere before.

However, this currently allows me to import and use it inside `packageB`. So, can I somehow block this behavior and ask to specify the library in package.json before using it, like PnP does?

Answer (score 0):

**Comment**:
I do not recommend having such directory structure. But in case code is obsolete, or anyother reason you need it , try like this

**Solution**:

```
npm install --save ../path/to/packageA
npm install --save ../path/to/packageB
```

**Output**:

```
{
  "name": "monorepo",
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA": "file:../path/to/packageA",
    "packageB": "file:../path/to/packageB"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've setup monorepo via yarn workspaces. So I can access my packages. The problem is if I add `libA` to `packageA` dependencies, it will be resolved **root** `node_moduIes`, so i still can use `libA` inside `packageB` without adding `libA` to `packageB` dependencies. And I'm trying to find some "strict mode" which is similar to Yarn PnP one's and will not allow me to use `libA` inside `packageB` if it's not in it's dependencies.